# Changing marker's size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is not it possible to change marker size in matplotlib?

```
from pylab import *    
x = [5,7,5,9,11,14]
y = [4,5,3,11,15,14]
scatter(x, y,color='green',marker='h')
show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify using `s` keyword argument:

```
scatter(x, y, s=500, color='green', marker='h')
#             ^^^^^
```

You can also specify individual marker size by passing a list:

```
scatter(x, y, s=[5, 50, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000], color='green', marker='h')
```

See [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter).